# elegant method of checking integer values in a list

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this method that returns a monster object based on an ID.

If the ID is in a certain array, in returns the definition.

It works!  But it just looks kind of hacky. The Ids might change, or I might need a new list of Ids, and it just looks bad in my opinion the way I have it setup now.

Is there a way to store the integers someplace else in the code, and then just do something like this?

```
if (room.Encounter.Id.MonsterType(dungeonMonsterTypes))
```

Here's the code I have now:

```
public static bool MonsterType<T>(this T item, params T[] list)
{
    return list.Contains(item);
}

public static MonsterDefinition GetMonsterDefinition(this Rgame room)
{
    var monster = room.Encounter.MonsterDefinition;
    if (room.Encounter.Id.MonsterType(190, 68, 115, 59, 40, 66, 112, 421))
        return new MonsterDefinition(monster);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at enum's ??

Comment: What happens if you call the `MonsterDefinition` constructor with another number?

Comment: The code does not make a whole lot of sense.  Why are you using `var monster` to describe whats already stored in the room object (`MonsterDefinition`).  Why are you then returning a new MonsterDefinition (that seems to be what you already have)

Comment: Also, this is why we don't use `var` when the type is not implied...

Comment: How often the number change? If the number changes then why do you need that to be hardcoded?

Comment: `Why did you name `room.Encounter.Id.MonsterType` like a property, but call it like a method?

Comment: It is an extension method - badly named though - maybe InMonsterTypes would be better - it checks if Id is in the parameter list.

Comment: As your method expects an array cant the numbers (or enums) be stored in an array named dungeonMonsterTypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HashSet -

```
HashSet<int> monsterIDs = new HashSet<int>() { 190, 68, 115, 59, 40, 66, 112, 421 };
...
if (monsterIDs.Contains(room.Encounter.Id))
  return new MonsterDefinition(monster);
```

You also could use an enum instead of pure int's, to be more readable.